# Why does connecting to different port result different error Node.js

Tags: node.js

a little background, I am self learning Node.js and I created a `hello.js` file on my mac and ran it using `node hello.js`. I can access the webpage page fine from either `localhost:port` or `127.0.0.1:port`.

My ultimate goal is to be able to access the web page from other machines. I looked through many SO pages. I added `'0.0.0.0'` in my `app.listen()` but still not successful so far, I am sure I will figure out later. I know there are many question and duplicates about how to connect to localhost from other machines devices, please don't get confused because that is NOT my question!

In my process of figuring out how to do so, I got curious of ***why when I try to connect to different port I get different errors from chrome from my other machine?***

This is my hello.js:

```
const http = require('http'); 

http.createServer((request, response) => {

    response.writeHead(200, {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain'
    });
    response.write('Hello, My name is Oliver\n');
    response.end();

}).listen(1337, '0.0.0.0', function() {
    console.log('Listening to port:  ' + 1337);
});
```

**port 1337:**
When I use port 1337 by running `node hello.js`
[image]

I can connect to the page fine on my mac using `127.0.0.1:1337`.
But when I try to connect it from my other machine (Windows) using Chrome I get

[image]

**port 2701**
Now when I use port 2701 again running `node hello.js`
[image]
again trying to connect it from my other machine using `127.0.0.1:2701` I get the following error from chrome:
[image]

**port 1433**
following the above steps then I get this error:

[image]

I didn't change the code at all but I when I switch different port I get different error. There are some posts about connecting to differnt ports with Node.js for example: 
[HTTPComponent Connect to different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8113723/httpcomponents-connect-to-different-port) or
[Node js route request to different port](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30212178/node-js-route-request-to-different-port-on-same-host)

But these posts didn't touch on why it result in different errors. Can someone please explain this behavior?

EDIT: I realize that `127.0.0.1` refers to my localhost so I would have to use my real IP address of my Mac. However my curiosity remains, **why does connecting to different ports on localhost result in different errors?**

Comment: when you are connecting from another machine you have to use its IP address,  `127.0.0.1` refers to localhost

Comment: gotcha I will update my question.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to access your server from another machine, you should use its real IP adress. 127.0.0.1 or localhost is for local use only.

E.g. your Mac has IP 123.456.789.123. By local call you can use 127.0.0.1, localhost or 123.456.789.123.
For remote call you have always to use 123.456.789.123.

Comment: ahh I suspected that this can help me solve the connection problem from my window machine. so currently I am connecting the local host of my windows machine, not my mac correct? so how is connecting to different ports on localhost result in different errors?

Comment: Hi @PaveGatnar here is my update: I used `ifconfig | grep "inet " | grep -v 127.0.0.1` in my terminal to get my IP which is 10.35.131.255 on my mac. I tried to connect to my server from Windows again using that `10.35.131.255:1337` but I get an error "ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT" says server took too long to respond. I also tried to connect to it on my mac itself using  `10.35.131.255:1337` then I get an error `ERR_NETWORK_ACESS_DENIED` says your internet access is blocked. Why does it behave this way?

Comment: It seams you have to configure the firewall settings on your Mac.